# Calculating transitive closures

Tags: isabelle

I have the following definition:

```
definition someRel :: "nat rel"
where
  "someRel = {(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)}"
```

I want to prove the following lemma:

```
lemma "someRel^*``{1}={1, 2, 3, 4, 5}"
```

I have devised the following proof:

```
proof 
  show "someRel^*``{1} ⊆ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}" 
  proof 
    fix x
    assume "x ∈ someRel⇧* `` {1}"
    then show "x ∈ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}"
      using assms someRel_def by (auto elim: rtranclE)
  qed
next
  show "{1, 2, 3, 4, 5} ⊆ someRel^*``{1}" 
  proof 
    fix x
    assume "x ∈ {1::nat, 2, 3, 4, 5}"
    then show "x ∈ someRel⇧* `` {1}" 
      using assms someRel_def Image_singleton by (induction) blast+
  qed
qed
```

This proof has the following issues:

- The first part (``` show "someRel^*``{1} ⊆ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}" ```) is proved using the rule
  `rtranclE`. This does not work if I add one more pair to the `someRel` relation (say the pair `(6, 7)`)
- The proof of the second part (``` show "{1, 2, 3, 4, 5} ⊆ someRel^*``{1}" ```) does not terminate.

Can anyone suggest a better proof? That (a) allows for more pairs in the `someRel` relation and (b) that terminates.

Comment: Minor comment: I wouldn't talk about a "proof" as long as there are nonterminating methods/tactics involved.

Comment: In the second part of your proof-attempt `using assms` does not really make sense (`assms` refers to the overall assumptions of your lemma, which are none at all). Also instead of `using someRel_def` you might want to *unfold* the definition of `someRel`, by `unfolding someRel_def`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that for your specific instance (and some slightly bigger ones I tried), the following suffices (found by first applying `auto` and then running `sledgehammer` on the remaining goals to identify useful facts, like `converse_rtrancl_into_rtrancl` here):

```
by (auto simp: someRel_def converse_rtrancl_into_rtrancl elim: rtranclE)
```

However, in general it might be a better idea to do one of the following:

1. device a tactic to prove such goals (by actually computing the involved transitive closure)
2. compute the transitive closure inside Isabelle/HOL (either via `simp` -- which might be slow -- or via `eval` -- which, as far as I know is kind of an oracle).

For the latter the AFP entry
[*Executable Transitive Closures*](http://afp.sourceforge.net/entries/Transitive-Closure-II.shtml) might be of interest.

**Update:** I added an example of a simproc that computes images of finite transitive closures over finite sets by evaluation to the development version of the AFP. Instead of *Executable Transitive Closures* however, I based the example on
[*Executable Transitive Closures of Finite Relations*](http://afp.sourceforge.net/devel-entries/Transitive-Closure.shtml). Your example can be found at the end of theory
[`Finite_Transitive_Closure_Simprocs`](http://afp.sourceforge.net/browser_info/devel/AFP/Transitive-Closure/Finite_Transitive_Closure_Simprocs.html) (as soon as the AFP website is synchronized with the underlying mercurial repository).

**Update:** Note that the above mentioned simproc is specifically aimed at patterns of the form ``` r^* `` x ``` where the sets `r` and `x` are finite in the sense that they are given in finite set notation `{x1, x2, ..., xN}`. Thus, in order to fire on a specific goal you might have to add additional facts / simp rules / simprocs / ... in order to normalize an expression into this form.

**Example:** If you had the goal

```
"(converse someRel)^* `` {1} = {1}"
```

you would have to add rules that actually "apply" the `converse` operation on the given finite set. The following would do:

```
lemma [simp]:
  "converse (insert (x, y) A) = insert (y, x) (converse A)"
  by auto
```

Now the goal could be solved via

```
  by (auto simp: someRel_def)
```

Comment: I think that in this case, the applicative proof looks better. I got the following:  

lemma "someRel^* ``{1}={1, 2, 3, 4, 5}"  
  apply (rule equalityI)
  apply (simp add: someRel_def Image_singleton)
  apply (rule subsetI, simp)
  apply (erule rtranclE, blast)
  apply (auto elim: rtranclE)
  unfolding someRel_def 
       by (auto simp: Image_singleton converse_rtrancl_into_rtrancl elim: rtranclE)

Comment: I can't access the theory that you have supplied. Is there anything wrong? Or I should just wait?

Comment: In principle just wait ... in the meanwhile you can directly access the mercurial repository [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/afp/code/ci/default/tree/thys/Transitive-Closure/Finite_Transitive_Closure_Simprocs.thy).

Comment: Yes, this proves the goal above quite effectively! :)

But what about this one:

`lemma "(someRel^-1)^*``{2}={1, 2}`

I could not prove it using the theory you have provided.

Comment: The scripts that you provided above no longer work with the most recent version of Isabelle.  Would it be possible to update them to make them compliant with the most current version?

Comment: @NunoAmálio: I only found a typo in my **Example** (now it is `... = {1}`), thanks for pointing that out. However, I'm not quite sure what else you mean by "the scripts you provided" and "the most recent version of Isabelle". In Isabelle2015 (the latest official version) everything should work now.

Comment: Well, I've updated the scripts and it works now with Isabelle 2015. Somehow, the previous version that I had locally was not working. Thanks for the scripts anyway: they're very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Chris' answer, here is a full version which uses the AFP-entry for transitive closures, and which does use `code-simp` instead of `eval`. `code-simp` is a bit slower than `eval`, but does not rely upon oracles.

```
theory Test
imports "$AFP/Transitive-Closure/Transitive_Closure_List_Impl"
begin

lemma to_memo_list: "(set xs)^* `` {a} = set (memo_list_rtrancl xs a)"
  unfolding memo_list_rtrancl Image_def by auto

definition someRel :: "nat rel"
where
  "someRel = {(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5,3)}" 

definition someRel_list :: "(nat × nat)list"
where
  "someRel_list = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5,3)]" 

lemma someRel_list: "someRel = set someRel_list" by code_simp

lemma "someRel^*``{4}={3, 4, 5}"
  unfolding someRel_list to_memo_list by code_simp

end
```